A puzzle from YOU to ME ;)
Your task is to place seven words, in correct order, next to the numbers below.

You don't have to listen to the whole song, just listen to the first part of it.. you know, the - - - - -. (2)
I can't find my towel, my hair is all - - - now. (1)
It's not like it's the first time you say this, you - - - - - do what you say! (2)
One - - - - of United States during WW2 was United Kingdom. (4)
I can't find my socks! Ahh maybe they're - - - - - the bed. (2)
God - - - - - you. (1)
You almost ate the whole cake, barely nothing - - - - for me! (2)

1. 
5.
10.
50.
100.
500.
1000.


I can fill in the gaps in the lines, but I'm unsure where to go from there. The numbers in parentheses must be important but they don't seem to correspond to individual letters in the blank words, or at the very least, I can't make sense of the resulting letters.

My other observation is that the seven number values are (rot13)gur inyhrf bs gur frira Ebzna Ahzrenyf, but again, there's no obvious connection to anything else in the puzzle.

@F1Krazy You're on the right track. Yeah the connection is not obvious, try think some more.

The list of words should be as follows:

 1. R[I]GHT
 5. O[V]ER
 10. E[X]TRO
 50. A[L]WAYS
 100. [C]URSE
 500. [D]RY
 1000. ENE[M]Y

Why? Well, the first thing I noticed on viewing this puzzle shortly after it was posted was that...

 ...the 7 numbers listed were all numbers commonly represented by Roman numerals (1=I, 5=V, 10=X, 50=L, 100=C, 500=D, 1000=M).

I also quickly came up with words that seemed to fit the blanks:

 You don't have to listen to the whole song, just listen to the first part of it.. you know, the INTRO. (2)
 I can't find my towel, my hair is all WET now. (1)
 It's not like it's the first time you say this, you NEVER do what you say! (2)
 One ALLY of United States during WW2 was United Kingdom. (4)
 I can't find my socks! Ahh maybe they're UNDER the bed. (2)
 God BLESS you. (1)
 You almost ate the whole cake, barely nothing LEFT for me! (2)

However, I struggled for a while to see how these could be connected via the enumerations in parentheses at the end of each line. I was also very confused by the title. After all, this isn't a puzzle 'from YOU to ME' from the OP's point of view - it would be a puzzle 'from ME to YOU'...

 And that's what's important here! Antonyms! So let's think of words that are antonyms of the 7 words we've found. We can soon come up with:

 INTRO → E[X]TRO (2)
 WET → [D]RY (1)
 NEVER → A[L]WAYS (2)
 ALLY → ENE[M]Y (4)
 UNDER → O[V]ER (2)
 BLESS → [C]URSE (1)
 LEFT → R[I]GHT (2)

 And when we examine these closely we see that there is a different Roman numeral in the indicated position for each of these antonyms - we have discovered our mystery words and our way to order them as requested!

 (In fact, note that each Roman numeral only appears once among all of the words in this set - the order is completely forced for us!)


Wow, I really went off-piste. The actual solution is far more elegant. Good work!

You got everything right, great job!

@Prim3numbah It stumped me for a fair while. The solution path only eventually hit me when I focussed on the title and why it would be significant - it was an important hint to the mechanism for sure :)

Definitely so :) I hoped that someone would make sense of the title since that was the only hint.

@Prim3numbah: As an aside, I would normally make the mapping VAGEB --> BHGEB, not RKGEB (trivially encoded to avoid spoilers). Maybe you could choose a different wording?

@BrianTung I thought about that too, so I agree on that, but that wording made it easier to figure out the specific word since VAGEB is commonly used when it comes to music.
